# Extract text based on color with title and sub titles

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document with the following format :

- Title level 1

  - First Title level 2

    Some text

    Some text in red
  - Second Title Level 2
    - Title level 3

    ```
        Some text

        Some more text in red
    ```

And would like to output the following :

```
Title level 1, First Title level 2, Some text in red
Title level 1, Second Title level 2, Title level 3, Some more text in red
```

My document contains some Embedded PDF file, table and images.
Output can be in a new file or in the actual file

The title are made using the "Style" feature from Word. Styles are named Title1, Title2, etc

I tried some thing with the Find fonction but didn't get any probant results. Plus I don't know how to get the titles as well

Any help is really appreciated even just pointing a direction
Thank you

Edit :
So I added a new Style called "Red Text" and apply it to the text I need to extract

Using this macro found online by Greg Maxey

```
Sub ScratchMacro()
'A basic Word macro coded by Greg Maxey
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
  With oRng.Find
    .Style = "TextInRed"
    While .Execute
      ActiveDocument.Range.InsertAfter vbCr & oRng
      ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = "Normal"
      oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Wend
  End With
End Sub
```

I can list all the "text in red" so its a starting point. Now looking to loop through that text run a .find on my original document and extract the titles. don't have code for that yet.

Comment: The document is a word file. There are PDF embedded but they just appear as an icon and should not be part of the process described above. It was just to inform that while the macro scans the  document it will see objects (pdf attachements) tables and images. These are to be ignored by the macro

Comment: I have edited my original post